# Rails model method for incomplete tasks failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, view, model, form-for

I have a few methods in my Task model to check if a task is incomplete, overdue, or completed. Overdue and complete work fine, but tasks that are incomplete simply don't show up in my view. If I run Task.incomplete in rails console, the incomplete tasks are returned.

Model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to  :agency
validates :name, presence: true

def self.overdue
    where("due_at < ? AND completed = ?", Time.zone.now, false)
end

def self.incomplete
    where("due_at >= ? AND completed = ?", Time.zone.now, false)
end

def self.completed
    where("completed = true")
end

end
```

View:

```
        - @current_agency.tasks.incomplete.each do |task|
                = form_for task do |f|
                    %tr
                        %td
                            = f.check_box :completed, :class => "taskCheckbox"
                        %td
                            = link_to task.name, '/tasks/'+task.id.to_s+'/edit'
                        %td
                            = task.due_at.to_date.strftime( "%m-%d-%Y" ) if task.due_at.present?
                        %td
                            = task.assigned_to if task.assigned_to.present?

                            = submit_tag 'Save', class: 'pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary', :style => 'display:none;'
```

Comment: do you get results if you run the query against your database directly?

Comment: Yes, I get the correct results if I run the methods in rails console: 

[87] pry(main)> Task.incomplete
  Task Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks"  WHERE (due_at > '2014-10-28 16:22:05.423169')
=> [#<Task id: 32, agency_id: 1, name: "Incomplete", assigned_to: "", content: "", location: nil, duration: nil, due_at: "2014-10-31 00:00:00", completed_at: nil, status: 1, created_at: "2014-10-28 16:12:05", updated_at: "2014-10-28 16:12:05", completed: nil>...

Comment: Figured it out, the issue was with Tasks that had a nil value for the "completed" attribute. I ran a migration to add a default => false for completed, and now it's good to go. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with Tasks that had a nil value for the "completed" attribute. I ran a migration to add a default => false for completed, and now it's good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Please, change your incomplete method to:

```
def self.incomplete
  where("tasks.completed IS NULL or tasks.completed = false")
end
```

This way a task is completed xor a task is incomplete. This may work when completed is nil, and when an incomplete task due_at >= Time.now.

Edit: add table_name, add NULL

Comment: Alejandro, I tried your suggestion, but no luck. I also tried: 

 def self.incomplete
  where("due_at >= ? AND completed != ?", Time.zone.now, true)
 end

Comment: Alejandro, I figured it out, the issue was with Tasks that had a nil value for the "completed" attribute. I ran a migration to add a default => false for completed, and now it's good to go. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I hope I was helpful.